# Hide and show element in php

Tags: php

I want to hide element in my website. I have 2 level access (ad,op). If I logged as sp I can acces Buy, Try, List Upload, and Upload. If I logged as ad, I can access Buy, Try, and List Upload. and not logged, can access Buy and Try.

My code : http://pastebin.com/SvZmzmxK

```
<p style="text-align:justify;">&nbsp;</p>
<strong>Buy  </strong> <strong> &nbsp; Try</strong>  
<?php if ($level=='super_admin') {?>
<strong> &nbsp; List Upload</strong></br></p>
<strong> &nbsp; Upload</strong></br></p>
<?php } elseif($level=='admin') {?>
<strong> &nbsp; List Upload</strong></br></p>
<strong> &nbsp; Upload</strong></br></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Consider undestanding difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: Change all `=` to `==`

Comment: learn more about [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: I cannot understand why people upvoted this question an why now the code is correct after the edit...

Comment: [**Your first code**](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20935988/1) had single `=` and now your pastebin has 2x. Which one is it?

Comment: I have edited it. Can you give me a solution?

Comment: Instead of going in and out of PHP, why don't you just simplify things and `echo` what you need based on the conditional statement?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: To : Fred-ii    if you can not give a solution please don't say anything, I just asked to people who could help me

Comment: **Listen pal**, I wasn't being "snotty" like you're answering me now. If YOU can't find a solution to something as **PETTY** as this, then you're in the wrong domain. **FIX IT YOURSELF**. And I don't usually give comments like these, unless someone is "OUT OF LINE" which you are. I was making a suggestion and then you come back with ***" if you can not give a solution please don't say anything'*** kind of **B.S.** @user3162889 P.s.: **Learn how to code properly**

Comment: I'm sorry, if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, this is probably just what you are looking for:

```
<?php 
if ($level=='super_admin')
  echo "<strong> &nbsp; List Upload</strong>";
else if elseif($level=='admin') 
  echo "<strong> &nbsp; List Upload</strong></br></p>
  <strong> &nbsp; Upload</strong></br></p>";
?>
```

I would recommend putting your php in a format like this (using echo) since it keeps your code easier to read and maintain.

I also advice you to look at your html knowledge: </br> and </p> can't just be used liked that.

Comment: Thank you so much,, working... I am Newbie,, btw thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
<p style="text-align:justify;">&nbsp;</p>
<strong>Buy  </strong> <?php //Buy for all; ?>
<strong> &nbsp; Try</strong> <?php //Try for all; ?>
<?php if( in_array($level,array('super_admin','admin')) ){ ?>
    <strong> &nbsp; List Upload</strong> <?php //Buy|Try|List Upload for ad+sp; ?>
    <?php if($level=='admin'): ?>
        <strong> &nbsp; Upload</strong> <?php //Upload is only for admin(ad); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```